# Is it possible to group a table's rows on the basis of same value in one of the columns in sapui5?

Tags: json, sapui5, treetable

I have implemented sap.ui.table.Table on the SAP HANA Cockpit. I have the first column as 'name'. This column may have multiple same values based on other parameters. I want this column to appear as nodes of these names where it may be possible to collapse out the entries belonging to that name. This may appear like a TreeTable. TreeTable, according to my understanding requires the json in a different fashion than what I have.
My json is as follows:

```
[{
    "ID": "1100",
    "Name": "John",
    "Date": "Oct 03, 2014",
    "Group": "A"
},
{
    "ID": "1100",
    "Name": "John",
    "Date": "Oct 28, 2016",
    "Group": "B"
},
{
    "ID": "1101",
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Date": "May 03, 2011",
    "Group": "A"
},
{
    "ID": "1102",
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Date": "Sep 25, 2016",
    "Group": "A"
},
{
    "ID": "1101",
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Date": "Oct 03, 2016",
    "Group": "C"
}]
```

Is it possible to group 'Name' based upon the 'Group' here?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to merge duplicate cells. There is an example in the OpenUI5 Explored Library ([Link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableMergeCells/code)). The attribute is also explained [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Column/properties).

The Column of your table have the attribute mergeDuplicates. If you set this attribute, duplicate cells are merged.